# How to extend a class in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop, implements

My service is designed in nodejs.
Below is my scenario
    i have two controllers, one will be extending  the other. there is a static function in both the controllers where in a static variable will be assigned some value.
    depending on the condition of the data, im trying the make a call to the respective controller so that the static variable gets a appropriate assigned value.

**Note:**

The below code is just a snippet to explain the scenario and not the actual code of the application. But the order / calling / controller structure of this code snippet is exactly same. Also the listOfDept variable will be having separate business logic in the checkStart function of firstController and secondController.

```
// firstController.ts
firstController implements IFirstController {
    private static listOfDept: string[];
    static checkStart(){
        firstController.listOfDept = // my logic to fill this object

    }
    constructor (){}
    }

    getRelevantData(next: (error: string, response: any) => void): void {
        var myObject = firstController.listOfDept;
        this.myRepository.uniqueData(myObject, next);
    }
}
firstController.checkStart();
export = firstController;

//ifirstController.ts

interface IFirstController {
    getRelevantData(next: (error: string, response: any) => void): void;
}

// secondController.ts
secondController extends firstController implements iSecondController {
    private static listOfDept: string[];
    static checkStart(){
        firstController.listOfDept = ["Computer Science"];

    }
    constructor (){
        super();
    }
}
secondController.checkStart();
export = secondController;

//isecondController.ts
interface ISecondController implements ifirstController{}

//Controller calling the getRelevantData function

//middlewareController

middlewareController implements IMiddlewareController {
  constructor(private firstController: IFirstController, private secondController: ISecondController) {
    }

    getDepData(data: any, next: (error: string, response: any) => void): void {
        if(data.url = "fromParent") {
            // im expecting this to make a call to checkStart() of firstController
            this.firstController.getRelevantData();
        } else {
            // im expecting this to make a call to checkStart() of secondController
            this.secondController.getRelevantData();
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem faced with the above code**

No matter which way the getRelevantData function is getting called, im always getting the value of *listOfDept*  as computer science. It is never going in the checkStart function of first controller.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would discourage using static methods for this kind of initialization and instead inject the required data into constructors or create factory methods for creating object with necessary data.

But, if you do want to use static properties, the problem is that you need to refer to the right parent class in the `getRelevantData` implementation. The class that constructed the instance can be accessed through `constructor` property. TypeScript does not process this scenario well, so you have to make a type cast:

```js
// firstController.ts
class firstController implements IFirstController {
  // Need to be `protected` to be accessible from subclass
  protected static listOfDept: string[];
  static checkStart(){
    firstController.listOfDept; // my logic to fill this object
  }

  constructor (){}

  getRelevantData(next: (error: string, response: any) => void): void {
    // You need to refer to the constructor
    let Class = this.constructor as typeof firstController;
    var myObject = Class.listOfDept;
    // the rest
  }
}
firstController.checkStart();

//ifirstController.ts

interface IFirstController {
    getRelevantData(next: (error: string, response: any) => void): void;
}

// secondController.ts
class secondController extends firstController implements ISecondController {
    // No `listOfDept` definition here
    static checkStart(){
        secondController.listOfDept = ["Computer Science"];
    }
    constructor (){
        super();
    }
}
secondController.checkStart();
```